# How to use rails undefined method `attr_accessible' in version 4 +?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new on rails. Below is what i am trying

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
    has_many :post
end
```

but i am not sure how to use  attr_accessible  in rails 4+ in my above scnerio .
I was doing as per old .Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4 + , there is no mass assignment support.

You have to pass in controller and use that like,

```
def create
  Category.create(category_params)
end

private

def category_params
  params.require(:category).permit(:name)
end
```

then call the category_params method in your controller actions.

Answer (score 1):

For rails 4 and above you do not need to use this just permit  your attributes in controller

```
 def category_params
   params.require(:category).permit(:name)
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

In rails 4 attr_accessible is deprecated you should use strong params

[Rails 4, Strong Parameters, and Deprecation of the attr_accessible Macro](http://easyactiverecord.com/blog/2014/04/01/rails4-strong-parameters-and-the-attr-accessible-macro/)